# Swapping bar button items

Tags: swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I'd like to swap a bar button item, depending on a `UISegmentControl` which I thought would be fairly straight forward.

My initial plan was:

- Create an `IBAction` for when the segment changes
- Work out which segment we are on
- Hide the appropriate button

The code was something like this

```
@IBAction func segmentChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
     UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) { () -> Void in
           if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
                barButtonA.hidden = true
                barButtonB.hidden = false
           } else {
                barButtonA.hidden = false
                barButtonB.hidden = true
           }
     }
}
```

That hid the right button as expected, but oddly, the space where the button was still remained, so it looked really strange.

Next I saw that in the interface builder there is a parent container (`UIBarButtonItem`s) for each of the buttons. I'm not sure why they're needed, but I hooked them up via `IBOutlets` so I could hide/show them in the function, but that didn't work either as they don't have a hidden property.

Finally, I tried to use those new outlets with following code:

```
@IBAction func segmentChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
     UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) { () -> Void in
           if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.barButtonItemA
           } else {
                 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.barButtonItemB
           }
     }
}
```

But no luck! Here, it just seems to animate swapping the two button positions/order, rather than actually removing either one.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yo should combine the two function you have.
So swap them and change the hidden state.

Update:
Did you tried to first delete the navigation.barbutton.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
```

Comment: I considered that, but why is that the right way to do it? Surely if you change the right bar button item, the other one should disappear?

Comment: There will always be a better way. But if it works you shouldn't bother to much with it for now.

Comment: I understand why you say that, but I'm trying to learn to do it properly, rather than find work arounds. Short cuts often lead to problems further down the line.

Comment: I don't think the it is that bad actually. of means of shortcut.